# kivy button text="" logic error

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new to python and kivy, I am trying to learn python bymaking a small minesweeper game, however, I feel the logic in below code is correct, but somehow seems not to work: complete file is as follows:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random

class spot(Button):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        super(spot,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ismine=False
        self.text="X"
        if 'id' in kwargs:
            self.id=kwargs['id']
        #else:
        #    self.text="X"    


class minesholder(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(minesholder,self).__init__(**kwargs)

class game(BoxLayout):
    spots={}
    mines=[]

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(game,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.m=minesholder(rows=5, cols=5)
        self.add_widget(self.m)
        self.attachtogrid()

    def attachtogrid(self):
        self.m.clear_widgets()
        self.spots.clear()
        for r in range(0,5):
            for c in range(0,5):
                idd=str(r)+","+str(c)
                self.spots[idd]=idd
                s = spot(id=idd)
                self.m.add_widget(s)
                s.bind(on_press=self.spottouched)
                print(idd)
        self.createmines()

    def createmines(self):
        self.mines.clear()
        count=0
        while (count <= 10):
            c=str(random.randint(0,4))+','+str(random.randint(0,4))
            print(c)
            if self.mines.count(c)==0:
                self.mines.append(c)
                count+=1        

    def spottouched(self,spotted):        
        #if self.mines.count(str(spotted.id))==1:
        #    spotted.text="BOMB"
        #else: spotted.text=""
        for k in self.mines:
            if k==spotted.id: spotted.text="BOMB"
            else:
                spotted.text=""
```

The issue is the last 4 lines, when I remove the "spotted.text=""", the code is working perfect, but when I keep the text="" the code is not working any more, despite of having 11 bombs only 1 is getting detected, with out the text="", all the bombs are getting detected correctly (text="BOMB" works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time `spottouched()` is called, you loop through each mine and set the text accordingly. But let's say you have two bombs - let's call the bombs `['bomb-a', 'bomb-b']`.

Now you touch the button with the id `'bomb-a'`. `spottouched()` loops through the mines. The first mine in the list is `'bomb-a'` - so it sets the text to `"BOMB"`. Then it loops - the second mine in the list is `'bomb-b'`, so the text is set back to `""`. So the only mine which will show the `"BOMB"` text is the very last mine in the list.

Try something like this instead:

```
def spottouched(self, spotted):
    spotted.text = "BOMB" if spotted.id in self.mines else ""
```

Comment: My bad, finally understood the error in logic, but your code is small and great.  Thank you.  It took me a while to understand what you said, and it takes a good mood too.